# How to disable to submit button if emailid is already exits using angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

i want to disable the submit button if the emailid is already exits in database using angularjs. but i'm not sure how to do so

here is my html code

```
<div data-ng-cloak data-ng-app="AddEmailModule" data-ng-controller="AddEmailController">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="AddEmailForm" name="AddEmailForm" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="" data-ng-submit="AddEmailData(AddEmail)"> 
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="emailid">Email-Id</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email-Id"  id="emailid" name="emailid" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-\_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-\_.]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,5}$" required  ng-change="check_email(emailid)" data-ng-model="AddEmail.emailid">                      
            <div class="error" data-ng-show="AddEmailForm.emailid.$dirty && AddEmailForm.emailid.$invalid">
                <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddEmailForm.emailid.$error.required">Email-Id is required.</small>
                <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddEmailForm.emailid.$error.email">Invalid Email-Id.</small>
            </div>                                          
            <p><strong class="error">{{getEmail}}</strong></p>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme" data-ng-disabled="AddEmailForm.$invalid">Add</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

in the above code submit button is disabled by default its will enable only the emailid is filled. but i want to disable the button if the email id is already database.

Here is my AngualarJS code.

```
var AddEmail = angular.module("AddEmailModule", [])
AddEmail.controller("AddEmailController", function ($scope, $timeout, $http, jsonFilter)
{   
    var logResult = function (data, status, headers, config)
    {
        return data;
    };

    $scope.check_email = function(emailid)
    {
        $http.post('check-email.php', { 'emailid': $scope.AddEmail.emailid })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config)
        {
            $scope.getEmail = logResult(data, status, headers, config);
        });
    };

    $scope.AddEmailData = function (AddEmail)
    {
        //Add code comes here
    };
});
```

check-email.php shows **Ok** if emailid is available and **Email-Id already exists** if emailid is already exits. Now i'm little confused how to disable the submit button based on these message ?

**Any help/suggestion ?**

Comment: you can use $scope.AddEmailForm.email.$setValidity("email", false) in your controller.

Comment: where to add this @Pawan Gupta 3

Comment: In your controller in success where you are checking if email exists..  if(data.length>0) { $scope.AddEmailForm.email.$setValidity("email", false) }

Comment: It should be $scope.FormName.FieldName.$setValidity("FieldName",false).. so in your case it will be $scope.AddEmailForm.emailid.$setValidity("email",false)

Comment: yes tried as you. But its showing error in console log TypeError: Cannot read property 'emailid' of undefined. it this about the angularjs version which i'm using ? my current version is  AngularJS v1.5.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136219/discussion-between-pawan-gupta-and-user1624540).

Answer (score 2):

create Boolean variable and if email already exist make variable true

```
var AddEmail = angular.module("AddEmailModule", [])
AddEmail.controller("AddEmailController", function($scope, $timeout, $http, jsonFilter) {

    $scope.emailExist = false;

    var logResult = function(data, status, headers, config) {
        return data;
    };
    $scope.check_email = function(emailid) {
        $scope.emailExist = false;
        $http.post('check-email.php', {
                'emailid': $scope.AddEmail.emailid
            })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.getEmail = logResult(data, status, headers, config);
                $scope.emailExist = true; // make this true if email exist 
            });
    };
    $scope.AddEmailData = function(AddEmail) {
        //Add code comes here
    };
});
```

In `ng-disabled` use multiple conditions

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme" data-ng-disabled="AddEmailForm.$invalid || emailExist">Add</button>
```

**EDITED**

please replace `check_email` function with this

```
 $scope.check_email = function(emailid)
    {
        $scope.emailExist = false;
        $http({
          url :'http://localhost:8080/app/check-email.php',
          method : 'POST',
          data :  { 
            'emailid': $scope.AddEmail.emailid 

          }
        }).then(function(response){
            $scope.getEmail = logResult(response.data);
            if(response.data=="Email-Id already exists")
            {  
              $scope.emailExist = true;
            }
        },function(response){ 
          $scope.emailExist = false;
        })
    };
```

reason i use `then` is `success` is removed from angular version 1.6.1
in php file you are not returning "OK" its returning "Email-Id already exists" so use that for if condition

Comment: inside success how did you make sure email is already exist or not

Comment: `if(data!="OK"){$scope.emailExist = true; }`

Comment: Its showing error in console "**ReferenceError: emailExist is not defined**"

Comment: did you declare this in you controller initially `$scope.emailExist = false;`

Comment: Yes. As you mentioned in your answer

Comment: can u please create a plnkr. it is hard to figure out the problem

Comment: This is the https://plnkr.co/edit/dNqaNS23NUVjESrl5FEp?p=preview i did't used plnkr till now please check it once

Comment: Thanks @sachila ranawaka **Edited** code  is working only when `data-ng-disabled="AddEmailForm.$invalid || emailExist` changed **||** as per @Rohit Answers

Comment: opps i forgot about it. glad its working . will update the anwser

Answer (score 2):

**Obserbvation :** Pass correct model value inside ng-change function.

**`ng-change="check_email(emailid)"`** should be **`ng-change="check_email(AddEmail.emailid)"`**

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.emailExist = true;
    $scope.alreadyRegMail = 'test@gmail.com';
    $scope.check_email = function(emailid) {
      if(emailid == $scope.alreadyRegMail) {
        $scope.emailExist = true;
      } else {
        $scope.emailExist = false;
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="AddEmailForm" name="AddEmailForm" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="" data-ng-submit="AddEmailData(AddEmail)"> 
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="emailid">Email-Id</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email-Id"  id="emailid" name="emailid" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-\_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-\_.]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,5}$" required ng-change="check_email(AddEmail.emailid)" data-ng-model="AddEmail.emailid">                      
            <div class="error" data-ng-show="AddEmailForm.emailid.$dirty && AddEmailForm.emailid.$invalid">
                <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddEmailForm.emailid.$error.required">Email-Id is required.</small>
                <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddEmailForm.emailid.$error.email">Invalid Email-Id.</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme" data-ng-disabled="AddEmailForm.$invalid || emailExist">Add</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohit Its working without changing ng-change. I just changed `data-ng-disabled="AddEmailForm.$invalid || emailExist`

Comment: @user1624540 mark this answer as correct if it is useful so that it will be helpful for others also.

Comment: All comments above answer are useful. That's why i did't accepted any answer. But marked comments as useful